# How i can get the immediate responses inside our "Start and wait for approval" that has "Wait for All Responses"

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, approval

Inside our automate flow we have the following "start and wait for approval" which has "wait for all responses", and it send the approval to a comma separated users' emails:-
[image]

now the approval step will keep running until all users response. but i need to get the immediate responses from the users and update a SharePoint list. for example let say we send the approval to 5 users, then once a user take an action inside the approval >> i need to get his/her response and update a SharePoint list.. currently we can not do so.. as we can only get the responses when all users provide an action.. any advice on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you would have to do an individual approval process for each approver on a parallel branch. So, if you had five approvers you would have five parallel branches.

**Update to address comment:**

I didn't think you could do this with an Apply to each loop, but it appears you can. Please see [Flow of the Week: Send parallel approval requests to a dynamic set of approvers](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/advanced-flow-of-the-week-send-parallel-approval-requests-to-a-dynamic-set-of-approvers/).

The trick is to set the Concurrency Control.

[image]

Comment: but i will not always have five approvals.. they might be 6 or 3 , so the number is dynamic.. i am thinking if i add the "start and wait for approval" inside an "APPly to each"?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: so in this case i should send separate approvals to the users and not using comma separated variable as shown in my picture? then place the "start and wait for approval" inside the "Apply for each"? where i think if i add the "Mail" array inside the "Start and wait for approval"'s Assigned To field >> then power automate will add an Apply to Each automatically .. am i correct?

Comment: This process is covered in the blog post Iinked, "Finally, iterate over the Approvers array with another Apply to each loop. This loop contains a Start an approval action and a condition that sends an approval or rejection notification based on whether the Response is “Approved” or “Rejected”. Note – you can reference the currently selected item (approver in this case) using Current item attribute."

Comment: yes seems the link you provided is exactly what i am looking for .. thanks